# Error when building angular with nx FATAL ERROR: v8::FromJust Maybe value is Nothing

Tags: node.js, angular

sometimes I got the following error when building a angular app with nx on the build server.

```
FATAL ERROR: v8::FromJust Maybe value is Nothing.
 1: 00007FF6CA27412F napi_wrap+133311
 2: 00007FF6CA20DD06 SSL_get_quiet_shutdown+63062
 3: 00007FF6CA20EB9D node::OnFatalError+301
 4: 00007FF6CAAD6BB5 v8::V8::FromJustIsNothing+53
 5: 00007FF6CA131D2A v8::internal::Isolate::isolate_root_bias+15114
 6: 00007FF6CA131BCD v8::internal::Isolate::isolate_root_bias+14765
 7: 00007FF6CA12C000 v8::internal::WasmTableObject::WasmTableObject+42832
 8: 00007FF6CA2C6002 uv_pipe_pending_type+4242
 9: 00007FF6CA2D0AA0 uv_loop_init+1024
10: 00007FF6CA2D0D4A uv_run+202
11: 00007FF6CA14CD3D v8::internal::interpreter::BytecodeLabel::bind+35501
12: 00007FF6CA1487F8 v8::internal::interpreter::BytecodeLabel::bind+17768
13: 00007FF6CA2C152D uv_poll_stop+557
14: 00007FF6CB071860 v8::internal::compiler::RepresentationChanger::Uint32OverflowOperatorFor+146368
15: 00007FFB6EBB84D4 BaseThreadInitThunk+20
16: 00007FFB71511821 RtlUserThreadStart+33
```

I think it has something todo with the connection because the stack trace is about lib_uv and somewhere it is returning a null where it should return a maybe.

Is this a node bug or has this something todo with angular or nx?
This bug was seen with the follow version

- node version 14.18.1.
- node version 16.13.1 x64
- node version 16.16.0 x64

Not seen with 18.17.1.
But this could also caused by the new build server with more memory and cores

Comment: please share node and npm versions. 
we experience the same error (coincidentally upgrading from angular 11 to 12) with nearly the same stack trace. we use npm/6.14.11 and node/v14.16.0

Comment: I experienced the same issue, randomly when upgrading from node 10 to node 14/16, and angular 12 to angular 13. Did you found the reason ?

Comment: I also experience  the same thing after upgrading from angular 12 to 13. Have anyone found a solution?

Comment: Same issue here when upgrading to angular 13. It is random. Any update?

Answer (score 17):

```
npm cache clean --force
```

just worked for me.

node - v16.10.0

ng - v12.2.9

Answer (score 1):

I started getting the same error on an Azure DevOps Pipeline that had previously been working fine.

Nothing had changed in the app that was failing; however, a new pipeline had been added that is running newer versions of Angular and related tools. I suspect that Node or something along those lines had been upgraded for the new pipeline and started causing problems with existing pipelines due to "leftovers".

The solution was simple: In the "Get sources" step, I changed the Clean Options from "Sources and output" to "All build directories". After doing that the problem went away.